# How to override Spring Cloud Stream rabbitConnectionFactory?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I have an application that uses Spring Cloud Stream with a custom Rabbit binder. Now I have to add some proxy configurations to the binder but I don't know how I can configure the binder. The binder does not inherit the Spring environment btw. Can anyone help me or give more context since I can't find anything related to that topic.

The binder should not inherit the Spring environment and I just want to know how I can change the default `rabbitConnectionFactory` behaviour.

I have searched trough the Spring Cloud Stream docs and Spring Boot docs but couldn't find anything

EDIT:

For more context, the Application is a library Project that i want to implement in other Applications to automatically register the configured Rabbit Events. But i want to avoid that any additional events use my library Binder

At the Moment I have a simple binder configuration at the moment in my Application properties:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      binders:
        myLibraryBinder:
          type: rabbit
          default-candidate: false
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host:
                port:
                virtual-host:
                username:
                password:
                requested-heartbeat:
                ssl.enabled:
```

And then my producers and consumers use that binder.

Answer (score 0):

> The binder should not inherit the Spring enviornment

So, it sounds like you do everything yourself. Then it would be great to see some code from you.

Anyway, the RabbitMQ binder solution still relies on some `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory`, which in most cases probably an instance of `CachingConnectionFactory`. That one has a ctor:

```
/**
 * Create a new CachingConnectionFactory for the given target ConnectionFactory.
 * @param rabbitConnectionFactory the target ConnectionFactory
 */
public CachingConnectionFactory(com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory) {
```

This `rabbitConnectionFactory` can be created via: `RabbitConnectionFactoryBean`. And that's where you can configure your RabbitMQ setting whatever way you require.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If i configure the rabbitConfigurationFactory this way, do all binders(if there are more) of the Project use this rabbitConnectionFactory or can i configure only my target Binder to use this rabbitConnectionFactory?

Comment: The `RabbitConfiguration` has a conditional `rabbitConnectionFactory` bean. So, if we provide our own, it will have an effect for all the Rabbit binder in your application. If you have several of them, then you need to look into an appropriate multi-binder configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/spring-cloud-stream/multiple-systems.html. Pay attention to that `spring.main.sources` you can provide for each binder's `environment`. That's where you can provide a custom `@Configuration` with your own connection factory.

Comment: You also may consider just to use a `RabbitConnectionFactoryBeanConfigurer` and let everything else to be handled by Binder auto-configuration. See the mentioned `RabbitConfiguration` for details.